# Center a Horizontal UL Nav Bar in a Div

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked before but after hours of searching i still cannot get my nav bar to center. I'm still new to this but I think it has something to do with the way I've made my nav bar, as I am having the same problem on other projects. The code displayed is for the top bar, but I am having problems with the lower bar as well. [here](http://www.aandaartandframe.com) is the site.

And here is the relevant code.

```css
    #topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #6d6e70;
    text-align: center;
    }

    ul.nav1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 760px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    /*FIX CENTER IM LOSING MY MIND*/
    top: 35px;
    }

    li.hnav {
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    }

    a.hnav {
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    font-family: Walkway;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    }

    a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6d6e70;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="topbar">
      <img src="AandAlogoFINAL1.png" alt="A and A Logo" id="logo">
      
      <ul class="nav1">
       <li class="hnav"><a href="index.html" class="hnav">Home</a></li>
       <li class="hnav"><a href="about.html" class="hnav">About</a></li>
       <li class="hnav"><a href="framing.html" class="hnav">Framing</a></li>
       <li class="hnav"><a href="gallery.html" class="hnav">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="hnav"><a href="community.html" class="hnav">Community</a></li>
      </ul>
      
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Position `ul.nav1` relatively, give it `margin: 0 auto` and a `height: 77px`.

[image]

```css
#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #6d6e70;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 760px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 77px;
}
li.hnav {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
a.hnav {
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-family: Walkway;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6d6e70;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <img src="AandAlogoFINAL1.png" alt="A and A Logo" id="logo">
  <ul class="nav1">
    <li class="hnav"><a href="index.html" class="hnav">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hnav"><a href="about.html" class="hnav">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hnav"><a href="framing.html" class="hnav">Framing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hnav"><a href="gallery.html" class="hnav">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hnav"><a href="community.html" class="hnav">Community</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, quick and easy:

```
ul.nav1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 3px solid red;
    width: 760px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 35px auto;
}
```

I visited your site and verified that it works on your page.

[image]

Comment: `display: inline-block` makes the container shrink to fit its contents. `margin: 35px auto;` means that the top and bottom margins are 35px thick and the left and right margins are automatically calculated. Since the left and right margins are both set to `auto` the rendering engine will try to make them equal and therefore center your nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute from your ul, just add:

```
.nav1{ 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

then add margin-top on your ul.